# adherent point and convergence in cocountable topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $(X, F)$ be a cocountable topology with an uncountable set $X$, and $E$ be a subset of $X$, and $x_0$ be a point in $X$.

(a) $x_0$ is an adherent point of $E$

(b) $x_0$ is either an interior point or a boundary point of $E$.

(c) There exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in $E$ which converges to $x_0$.

Show that  it is possible for (a) and (b) to hold without (c) holding.

I know that (a), (b), (c) are equivalent in the metric space. I also know that (a) and (b) are equivalent in topological space. Thus, I need to show that either (a) or (b) holds without (c) holding.

If $x_0$ is an adherent point of $E$, for any neighbourhood of $x_0$, $V_{x_0}$, $V_{x_0} \cap E \not= \emptyset$. But, if every $V_{x_0} \cap E$ is finite, then there exists no sequence in E converging to $x_0$.

But this seems insufficient. Can you help me to finish this proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example is $X = \mathbb R$, $E = \mathbb R - {0}$, $x_0 = 0$.